# Error - Incorrect object inserted - Word 2003

Tags: microsoft-word-2003, microsoft-visio-2003

I'm editing a 150-page document on Word 2003. I inserted a graphic made with Visio 2003 (Visio 2003 Standard is installed locally).

When I try to print it, my graphic disappears and the only thing I see is the following:

> Error - Incorrect object inserted.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: ... That's what she said?

Comment: So Luke... any good idea?

Comment: How are you adding the graphic? Copy and paste from Visio to Word? Or are you converting it to a JPEG or PNG or similar format?

Comment: I just copied and pasted it. I'll give it a shot

Comment: And what type of printer are you using? PCL, GDI, PS?

Comment: I'm using a PS one. HP 4250

Comment: If you try printing to say, the XPS printer or a PDF file, or any other type of printer, does it still crash?

Comment: Try paste special as a Microsoft Metafile image.